# Redis Sentinel output in conf file

Tags: redis, redis-sentinel

I was testing Redis Sentinel's failover ability. It worked, and Sentinel added some lines to the conf files. It auto-discovered the other sentinels and slave replicas, but it added some weird ids.

Can anyone tell me what those ids represent? Since they come right after known-sentinel, I assume they are the id of those sentinels but I can't be sure.

```
# Generated by CONFIG REWRITE
sentinel known-slave redis_master 127.0.0.1 6379
sentinel known-slave redis_master 127.0.0.1 6381
sentinel known-sentinel redis_master 127.0.0.1 26380
26f81b692201f11f0f16747b007da9d4f079d9d3  # this
sentinel known-sentinel redis_master 127.0.0.1 26381
0b613c6146bbf261f08c1b13f1d1b2dbc2f99413 # and this?
```

Answer (score 0):

It's the run_id of sentinel. Remember sentinel is a special redis instance. Log into the sentinel and using "info server" to see its information, which includes the run_id. e.g.

```
redis-cli -h sentinel_host -p sentinel_port
info server
```

If you have multiple sentinels, you can use

```
sentinel sentinels mymaster(or redis_master in your situation)
```

to list **all other sentinels**' infomation.